# Working with Realm and services using MVVM

Tags: mvvm, swift3, realm, alamofire

I'm trying to refactor a project to a MVVM pattern using Realm and Alamofire.

I dont find a precise answer of where I should make my API calls and where I must use Realm to write datas to DB. My guess is it' should be in the Model.

Example, I want to show user profile. Is this example is correct and where should I make my API calls ? My problem is that I need to create many static/class function for Services and Models and I can't use auto-update Results.

```
// Model
class User: Object {
    class function get(whereIdentifier identifier: Int) {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "identifier = %d", identifier)
        return realm.objects(Runner.self).filter(predicate).first
    }
}

// ViewModel
struct UserViewModel {
    init(user userModel: User) {
    }

    static func get(whereIdentifier identifier: Int) -> UserViewmodel? {
        // Return a UserViewModel to show on the ViewController
    }
}


// I got a service like
struct UserService: Networkable {
     func get(whereUser user: User, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<User>) -> Void) {
        // Return a user from API
     }
}


// I got a service like
struct UserService: Networkable {
     func get(whereUser user: User, completionHandler: @escaping (Result<User>) -> Void) {
        // Return a user from API
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We have handled this problem this way.

1. The ViewController makes a request to our APIManager
2. The APIManager is responsible for making the API call with Alamofire and reading the JSON response.  It calls to our DataManager(which is an abstraction on your `User.get` method) to create the appropriate Realm objects and Create/Update/Delete them in Realm.  We use ObjectMapper to handle the mapping in each Model Object
3. The ViewController also creates an autoupdating query object from our DataManager.
4. The ViewController also subscribes to `realm.notifications` for any changes that occur as a result of the API response.

It looks something like this (semi-psuedo code):

```
var users:Results<User> = DataManager.shared.objects(User.self, whereIdentifier: id)
notificationToken = realm.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (notification, realm) in
  self?.updateViewModel()
}
updateViewModel()
APIManager.shared.loadUser(id: id)     

func updateViewModel() {
    //parse users data into whatever format you need for your VM
}
```

Comment: Hum it was one of my idea but it's not pure MVVM because the view reference a model (in fact Realm object but it's the same right ?) _The ViewController also creates an autoupdating query object from our DataManager._ Also it means to have many reference to RealmSwift everywhere in the project. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: And it's not the job of view to make API calls; IMHO!

Comment: @Ludovic imo it should be possible by adding the notificationBlock on a realm result instead of the realm (since realm results are just datas it makes sense?), at least that is why i am trying to implement